# Loop not working for character columns in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, class

I am trying to convert data class (from character to numeric) for certain df columns for a certain df inside a list; however when I run the next code a warning arises and the data class remains the same.

```
## inspecting class ##
class(df_list[["df"]][["col1"]])

//console output //
"character"


## function to return numeric ##
num_fun <- function(x){
             if(is.na(x)){
               return(NA)
             } else {
               as.numeric(x)
             }
}

numeric_columns <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

# loop to convert character columns ##

for(i in seq_along(numeric_columns)){
      df_list[["df"]][, i] <-  lapply(
                                    df_list[["df"]][, i],
                                    num_fun)
}

// console output //
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(8, 8, 8,  ... :
  provided 1203 variables to replace 1 variables
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introducidos por coerción


## verify ##
class(df_list[["df"]][["col1"]])

// console output //
"character"
```

Is there anyway to apply this function over specific column df list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
df_list[["df"]][numeric_columns] <- lapply(df_list[["df"]][numeric_columns], as.numeric)
```

This will convert the column in `numeric_columns` in `df_list[["df"]]` to numeric. `NA` would be kept as `NA` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` approaches to do this. Extract the `list` element specify the vector of `numeric_columns` in `across` and convert to `numeric`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_list[["df"]] <- df_list[["df"]] %>%
                     mutate(across(numeric_columns), as.numeric))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
Map(as.numeric, df_list[["df]][numeric_columns])
```